# Continued Difficulties with Python Question

Tags: python

I asked this question earlier and am still having difficulties. I tried a new approach that isn't working. Essentially, I'm trying to implement a program that performs a calculation using Python objects to represent data. I want to determine the name of the county that had the highest voter turnout in a previous election, as well as the percentage of the population who voted. I need to use two function names, but can manipulate them however I see fit. Here's what I currently have and not sure what mistake I'm making here:

```
  #creating a dictionary to store the country name and its percentage
  data = {}
  #creating the class county
  class County:
    def __init__(self,county,population,voters):
      self.country = country
      self.voters = voters
      self.population = population
      self.sorted_data = ""
      self.formatted_percentage = ""

  def highest_turnout(data) :
    highest = data[0]
    highest_percent = (data[0].voters / data[0].population)
      for data in County
          if (County.voters / County.population) > highest_percent
            highest = County
            highest_percent = County.data


  allegheny = County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469)
  philadelphia = County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069)
  montgomery = County("montgomery", 568952, 399591)
  lancaster = County("lancaster", 345367, 230278)
  delaware = County("delaware", 414031, 284538)
  chester = County("chester", 319919, 230823)
  bucks = County("bucks", 444149, 319816)
```

I need the “highest_turnout” function to do this:

- Find the County that has the highest turnout, i.e. the highest percentage of the
  population who voted, using the objects’ population and voters attributes
- Return a tuple containing the name of the County with the highest turnout and the
  percentage of the population who voted, in that order; the percentage should be
  represented as a number between 0 and 1
- Display the results of any “print” functions, as well as the last one which prints the return value of the function. Note that your highest_turnout function should correctly determine the County with the highest turnout for any input list

Any explanations / advice on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated. Thank you as I'm pretty new to Python and want to learn as much as possible.

Comment: Please update your question with a question.

Comment: There are numerous errors in your example code - please fix.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site.  This site works best if you can make your question very specific.  For instance, if you have a particular error message when you run your code and you don't understand it, ask about that.  If you want more general feedback on your code, you might want to try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead.

Comment: `Any explanations / advice on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated` Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.  Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks everyone, apologies for the non-specific question. This makes a lot of sense though and realize that there are numerous errors in my code. I'm reviewing the 'How to Ask' and will ensure to ask more pointed questions moving forward. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

```
#creating a list to store the country name and its percentage
data = []

#creating the class county
class County:
  def __init__(self,county,population,voters):
    self.county = county
    self.voters = voters
    self.population = population
    self.sorted_data = ""
    self.formatted_percentage = ""

def highest_turnout(data) :
  sorted_data_by_turnout = sorted(data, key=lambda county: county.voters / county.population, reverse=True)
  highest_turnout_county = sorted_data_by_turnout[0]
  return highest_turnout_county.county, (highest_turnout_county.voters / highest_turnout_county.population)


data = []
data.append(County("allegheny", 1000490, 645469))
data.append(County("philadelphia", 1134081, 539069))
data.append(County("montgomery", 568952, 399591))
data.append(County("lancaster", 345367, 230278))
data.append(County("delaware", 414031, 284538))
data.append(County("chester", 319919, 230823))
data.append(County("bucks", 444149, 319816))
print(highest_turnout(data))
```

FYI: there were some indentation errors in your code

Comment: What is the point of the line: `highest = data[0]`?

Comment: YOu're right I forgot to remove useless lines of code, editing